# call external PHP script with parameters

Tags: php, url

From a PHP page (`http://example.com/test.php`), I would like to call another PHP file located on another web site (`http://newsite.example.net/version.php`) and passing parameters (var1=123, var2=789). Version.php should do something and return true or false, so I can test the result in test.php (if ($result) ...)

Any short exemple how to proceed and what should be the content of the fileversion.php ?

Regards,
David

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: basicaly I want to create a very small version updater check. the file version.php should check based on the parameters if there is or not a newer version and return true or false.

Comment: But, you're stuck with every single step involved? Composing a URL, connecting to a remote site, comparing two strings?

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do, what I miss is how to send the result back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing a php script in such a way is equivalent to performing an http query. As such, the only result you can expect from the url you call is a http response (plain text, image, json - whatever mime type the page can output).

It can be done for example with **file_get_contents()** (provided your php configuration allows it) :

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://somesite.com/somepage.php?someparameter=somevalue');
```

You could then process the resulting content text however you like. But you won't ever get direct boolean output. numbers (0 or 1) could be suitable replacements for your needs, however.

---

Edit:

The version.php might look like this :

```
<?php if($condition) { echo 1; } else { echo 0; }
```

Comment: Understood, but I am still a bit lost about the content of the file version.php, especially how to output my result.

Comment: Updated the answer. feel free to change the $condition with something useful. If you need anything more elaborate (arrays, objects, etc), consider outputing json instead of plain text.

Comment: GREAT. It works fine. Many thx, You saved me a lot of time....